# Looking for refresh key

Tags: excel, formula, hotkeys

When I edit a formula bar I press f2 then use arrow keys to change data to see if it is working as expected.

When I change data all I know how to do is press enter. I then need to press arrow key to go back to cell, F2 again, use arrow keys just to go back to same place.

Is there a button or hotkey I can press that won't move my cursor out of formula bar but will refresh the workbook

Comment: Refreshing won't have any effect until the new value is accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable moving down on Enter key in Excel 2007?](https://superuser.com/q/140801/52365)

Comment: Can I get it to accept new value without having to leave formula bar and cell?

Comment: Without leaving the cell, [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440964/looking-for-refresh-key#comment73938876_43440964), without leaving the formula bar, no, but that's not a big problem if you don't leave the cell.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your link helped but I like using enter to go back to beneath tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing Ctrl+Enter instead of Enter. With Ctrl+Enter, the selection will remain in the formula cell.

Comment: Although note that it's just a side effect. Ctrl+Enter is not the specific hotkey to stay in a cell after edit, it's a hotkey to edit several cells at once. It will copy your edit to the entire selection (and stay in the active cell).

Comment: True. But what's the point here? When editing a formula while a single cell is selected, Ctrl+Enter will confirm the formula in a single cell. And when the same formula is being edited in multiple cells at the same time, Ctrl+Enter will confirm the formula in all the multiple cells at the same time and the selection will remain in the active cell of the selection.

Comment: Not criticizing your answer @sktneer, only trying to save confusion for future readers who might pick up Ctrl+Enter without realizing why it does what it does and that it can do more.

Comment: I didn't take it as a criticism as well. :)